# Issues with displaying and/or storing content of a Text File in C#

Tags: c#

For my Intermediate C# Class I'm tasked with pulling and maintaining data in a .txt file connected to the program via a filestream. Everything I understand about my coding is correct but when the form loads it's not pulling the data. I've troubleshot it from every angle I can think of but I'm at a loss for where I am. I'll include the relevant bits of code below, but I have a class with methods specifically to handle the filestream and data fill, as well as a class for "Student Objects".

Here is the data in the .txt file that I'm trying to read

Jeff Dickson|100|97|68

Sharon Beaudry|95|76|87

Hallie Neupert|95|89|94

Here is the method I have in the StudentsDB class to pull from the source file

```
public static List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            //Creates a new list to be returned
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            //Creates a new file stream to read the data
            StreamReader filler = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));
            //Starts the fill loop
            while(filler.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string row = filler.ReadLine();
                //Creates an array to fill with the line, deliniated by the pipe
                string[] columns = row.Split('|');
                //Creates an instantiation of the Student Class to use for filling purposes
                Student student = new Student();
                //Adds the student name from the array to the Student Object
                student.Name = columns[0];
                //Creates a loop that will go through the string array and pull the scores to add to the list
                //Converting them to integer in the process
                for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)
                {
                    student.Scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(columns[i]));
                }
                //Adds the instance of the student object to the list
                students.Add(student);
            }
            //Closes the stream and returns the list 
            filler.Close();
            return students;
```

Here is the Student Class with the properties and methods:

```
public class Student
    {
        //General Constructor
        public Student()
        { }

        //Public Properties
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List<int> Scores
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string GetDisplayText()
        {
            string total = "";
            foreach (int score in Scores)
            {
                total += "|" + score;
            }
            return Name + total;
        }
    

    }
```

And here is my method to fill the list box with each of the student items:

```
//Program wide variable for a list of students
        public List<Student> students = null;

        //Method to fill the list box
        private void FillBox()
        {
            //Clears the list box in order to allow for the data to be entered
            lstStudents.Items.Clear();
            //Fills the students list variable using the method from studentDB class
            students = studentDB.GetStudents();
            //Cycles throught the list and fills the list box
            foreach(Student s in students)
            {
                lstStudents.Items.Add(s.GetDisplayText());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, could you specify "it's not pulling the data"? ;) What troubles you? Is your filestream not working? Do you have exceptions/errors? Or is everything loaded, but your form isn't displaying what you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure where the disconnect is. I don't think the issue is with the filestream as if I set the lstStudents.Items to display just the list.tostring() it displays "Collection". I think the issue is with how I am parsing the data in to the Students object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You aren't initializing `Student.Scores` in the constructor, so it will be `null`. You can't add items to `null`.
- It'd be easier to check whether `.ReadLine()` returns `null` and `break` if it does instead of `Peek`ing the reader.
- You should be using an `using()` block for the `StreamReader` instead of manually managing `.Close()`.

Beyond that, things seem to work.

Comment: So do List properties behave differently than other properties when set in a class? After looking at your answer this might actually be the problem and I'll try this when I get back to my assignment later today.

Comment: This did it. Added the explicit constructors did the job. It also helps if I add the file extension for the file.

Answer (score -1):

i've not tested this but i've had trouble before with accessing data in string arrays. in your GetStudents() function you have:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length; i++)

 {

     student.Scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(columns[i]));
 }
```

when i had a similar issue i did:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < columns.Length -1; i++)

 {

     student.Scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(columns[i]));
 }
```

Arrays start at 0 in most programming languages. If you have an array of 3 elements, you have 3 positions available - positions 0, 1 and 2. As a result, fetching the length would return 3, so you need to subtract 1 to get the last element, the element at position 2.
https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/639159-actionscript-arraylength-1/

Comment: I will for sure try this when I get back to this assignment.

Comment: This will not help - in fact, it will introduce a bug where the last score for the student is not read in.